# StringList inside ArrayList using processing

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

I'm entering data from txt file into a set of `StringLists` using processing. I now want to put that `StringLists` into an `ArrayList`, one by one. 
However all the `StringLists` are entering into the same `ArrayList` index, which is `0`.

```
StringList lista = new StringList();
String [] listv;
ArrayList <Via> listaVias = new ArrayList();
Via via= null;

void setup() {
    int contador = 0;
    String lines [] = loadStrings("data.txt");
    Via ultimaVia = null;
    for (String linha : lines) {

        String[] params = split(linha, TAB);
        float score = parseFloat(params[0]);
        listaVias.add(via=new Via(score));
        for (int i=2; i<params.length; i++) {
            via.append(params[i]);
            //listaVias.add(via); 
        }


        println(listaVias);


        if (ultimaVia!=null && ultimaVia.isEqual(via)) {
        } else {
            if (via.size()>3) {

                contador++;

                if (contador==100) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


    ultimaVia = via;
  }
}
```

This is my Via class

```
class Via extends StringList {

    final float score;

    Via(float score) {
        super();
        this.score = score;
    }

    boolean isEqual(Via via) {
        if (this.size() == via.size()) {
            for (int i=1; i<via.size();i++) {
                if(!via.get(i).equals(this.get(i))){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

SAMPLE OF TXT

```
0.999999999197  4   BAI2    SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   GRK6    SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   JUNB    SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   BZRAP1  SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   RNPEPL1 SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   SBF1    SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   TRABD   SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   LDB1    SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   VEGFB   SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999999197  4   SKI SMAD2   SMAD4   SMAD3
0.999999994595  3   SLC25A22    JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   S100A6  JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   FXYD2   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   STK40   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   HDAC7   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   CLCN6   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   PRDX2   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   MYL6    JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   WDR82   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   ADM JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   SNRPG   JUN EP300
0.999999994595  3   ZYX JUN EP300
0.999999994402  4   SLC25A22    FOS JUN EP300
0.999999994402  4   S100A6  FOS JUN EP300
0.999999994402  4   FXYD2   FOS JUN EP300
0.999999994402  4   STK40   FOS JUN EP300
0.999999994402  4   HDAC7   FOS JUN EP300
```

THE PRINTLN RESULT:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xchu.png

Comment: Provide a sample of your input file to better understand the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Just edited it. it's creating Via stringLists with each line of my txt. That part is working fine. The problem is that I can't put each of that StringsLists in a diferent ArrayList index.

Comment: when you do the println(listaVia) what do you see, your code looks fine, it does not look as if everything is in index 0

Comment: it prints all data into a single index. if I do println(listaVias.get(2)) to get the index 2 of the ArrayList it gives me the error IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:2, Size1. I'll update the Question with a print

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example? It is currently impossible to help, we don't how you read your file `loadStrings("data.txt")`, how you split your file `split(linha, TAB)` and how you print your file `println(listaVias)`.

Comment: I getting a hard time understanding the issue with my post. I can't provide you a runnable example because the only thing this does is print information into the console. loadStrings() is a processing function that allows to get data from a text file. I'm spliting the text per line. This part is working fine and not the reason of the question. Every line is entering into a individual StringList called via. The problem is when I try the put that data in an array, it all goes to the same array index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing an `ArrayList` in the form `println(listaVias)` will result in the list being printed like this: `[item1, item2, item3]`. From the looks of your `println` example, each item is added to the list correctly.

The `println(listaVias.get(2))` will cause an  `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:2, Size1` to be thrown **on the first iteration** of the `for (String linha : lines)` loop, because at that stage, **there is only one item in the list**.

You will be able to get each item from index after the list has been populated.